# How to set a global Carbon format in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I've just upgraded my Laravel application from `6.x` to `7.x` and I'm having problems with dates/timestamps. I know some things changed in regards to that.

I'm trying to set a default `Carbon` format globally. I've got a few custom `timestamp` fields in my database, created like so:

`$table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();`

And I started getting following errors after upgrade, whenever these fields are updated:

`Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2020-04-04T11:00:00.000Z' for column 'published_at'`

I tried to use the suggested method on each `model`:

```
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

But this method never gets called, and it doesn't work.

However, setting up a mutator works fine:

```
public function setPublishedAtAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

But I was trying to avoid the repeated code for these fields. In total, there are about 14 fields where I'd need to create these mutators, so I was wondering if there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. I just had to add these timestamps to

```
protected $dates = [];
```